# Flutter: Search bar with dynamic content from a database

Tags: android, ios, mysql, flutter, dart

I am currently developing a flutter app.
For a group system, I need to create the group and add members to it.
I want the user who creates the group to enter the name of the user he wants to add in a search field. And then see if the user account exists. The whole thing should work dynamically. While typing the name the results should change. You can imagine it just like a search for a user on Instagram or Facebook.

What is the best way to do this? Which widgets do I use and do I have to get all registered users from the database, because that doesn't look very performant to me.

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT 1: Answer to @LacticWhale

I managed to get all the users from the database in a list of my model objects. So I have cut out the first and last name to pass this list to the UserSearchView class. However when I want to load the widget, it does not work, because some assertions fail. Here is my code:

UserSearchView Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserController extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserController({
    this.name = '',
  });

  String name;

  void changeName(String newName) {
    name = newName;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class UserSearchView extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserSearchView({
    required this.controller,
    required this.users,
    super.key,
  });

  final UserController controller;
  final List<String> users;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _UserSearchViewState();
}

class _UserSearchViewState extends State<UserSearchView> {
  String _name = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _name = widget.controller.name;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(widget.users
            .where((element) => element.contains(_name))
            .elementAt(index)),
        itemCount:
            widget.users.where((element) => element.contains(_name)).length,
      );
}
```

UI-Page (parts of it):

```
TableRow(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: textController,
                  onChanged: (value) => userController.changeName(value),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Suchen",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor),
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                        onPressed: () {
                          textController.text = '';
                          userController.changeName(textController.text);
                        },
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            TableRow(
              children: [
                UserSearchView(
                  controller: userController,
                  users: getUserNames(userList),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

getUserNames function:

```
List<String> getUserNames(List<User> userList) {
  List<String> userNames = List.empty();
  for (var user in userList) {
    userNames.add("${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}");
  }
  return userNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all users from data base.

Create statefull widget with searched users (MySearchView).

Create controller (extend `ChangeNotifier`) with field `name` (`String`, default to ''?) add method newName and assign new newName to name and call method notifyListner

In your MySearchView with fields controller (Your controller)

Create State (_MySearchViewState) override initState by adding listner to controller and in build create your search list

Code:

```dart
class MyController extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyController({
    this.name = '',
  });

  String name;

  void changeName(String newName) {
    name = newName;

    notifyListeners();
  }

}

class MySearchView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySearchView({
    required this.controller,
    required this.users,  
    super.key, 
  });

  final MyController controller;
  final List<String> users;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MySearchViewState();

}

class _MySearchViewState extends State<MySearchView> {
  String _name = '';
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _name = widget.controller.name;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
      widget.users.where((element) => element.contains(_name)).elementAt(index)
    ),
    itemCount: widget.users.where((element) => element.contains(_name)).length,
  );

}
```

Edit: forgot in your TextField add onChange: (value) => controller.changeName(value)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please reply to my most recent edit :)

Comment: Is "some assertions fail" about widget is already being build?

Comment: Yes, the exception gets thrown in the widget build method. I think that I am doing something wrong with UserSearchView. Where should I put it in the build method of the UI-Page, because if I comment out the part with the UserSearchView, it runs just fine. So how do I tell the TextFormField to take the list of User names assearch content?